# Acer TimelineX 4820TG fan speed out of controll after install Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, cpu, bios

Laptop Acer Aspire TimelineX 4820TG. 
Dual boot Windows 7 and Ubuntu 10.10 
Despite some small bugs the machine runs fantastic with this software. 
After installing Ubuntu 12.04 the cooling fan runs like crazy. Even if I just in BIOS the fan starts crying at full speed as well as when I boot Windows 7 
In BIOS there is no possibility to influence the fan control.It seems the BIOS is different from other machines. (No advanced / Power / tap) 
Does anybody have a idea how to set the fan control back to the old settings. 
Please do not talk in short cuts and in Computer language I am only a advanced user 
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple; update BIOS. There is a BIOS update for your laptop on the Acer home page which is mentioned as a fix for fan problems. 
When I installed the update the fan immediately runs as it used to. I could install it with windows because I dual boot. 
If anyone has this problem after installing, this is how you fix it.